# How to sort a multidimensional array by two keys

Tags: arrays, wordpress, sorting, usort

i have the following array.
How can i sort this first by tabelle_punkte, then by tabelle_tore?

I tried to use usort but i am not sure how to exactly use it.

Any tipps?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tabelle_id] => 113
            [tabelle_mannschaft] => 21
            [turnier_id] => 168
            [tabelle_runde] => vorrunde
            [tabelle_gruppe] => A
            [tabelle_platz] => 1
            [tabelle_spiele] => 1
            [tabelle_tore] => 2
            [tabelle_gegentore] => 2
            [tabelle_punkte] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tabelle_id] => 114
            [tabelle_mannschaft] => 1
            [turnier_id] => 168
            [tabelle_runde] => vorrunde
            [tabelle_gruppe] => A
            [tabelle_platz] => 1
            [tabelle_spiele] => 2
            [tabelle_tore] => 2
            [tabelle_gegentore] => 2
            [tabelle_punkte] => 3
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```php
usort($your_array, function($a, $b){
    if($a['tabelle_punkte'] == $b['tabelle_punkte']){
        if($a['tabelle_tore'] == $b['tabelle_tore'])
             return 0;
        else if($a['tabelle_tore'] < $b['tabelle_tore'])
             return -1;
        else
             return 1;
    }
    else if($a['tabelle_punkte'] < $b['tabelle_punkte'])
        return -1;
    else return 1;
});
```

Comment: thanks it helped a lot to understand the use of the usort!

Comment: @MichaelH. basically you have to pass it an array, and a function, which will be used to order the elements, and so you have to return 0 if you retain that the two elements should be considered equal, -1 if the first should be considered less than the second, otherwise 0